# Acumatica renders incorrect date in Activity GI

Tags: acumatica

We have created an Activity from Employees screen with Start date of 3/11/2020 and end date as 3/27/2020.

I also created a GI for Activities, I have used CRActivity table to display Activities.

The issue is that the end date is displaying one day less than the selected date, see the below screenshots.

We are using Acumatica 2019 R1 - Build 19.106.0020

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a time component 5:00 PM which is present on screen but not in DB. Maybe that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Are you in GMT-7 timezone?  It looks like the screen is displayed exactly like it is in stored in the database as GMT, but your GI might be adjusting for local timezone.

Comment: Hi John. Some feedback: it is ideal if each of your question titles can be a succinct summary of the problem you are having. A number of them are "Need help with X", which is not particularly specific. A good formulation is to start questions with "How to" and then write a small sentence, possibly as a question, that describes what is not working as expected. I have tried to edit this one for you.

Comment: There is also a helpful-looking answer below that you have forgotten to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the database is going to store the dates in UTC time so it seems Acumatica is doing some formula on it in your GI. If I do the same, my time zone should be getting 4 hours less in the GI than what is in the DB but I get the same +5 hours you see for some odd reason.

```
    SELECT 
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), StartDate) AS StartDateInLocalTime, 
StartDate, --this is UTC Time
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), EndDate)   AS EndDateInLocalTime, - 
EndDate, --this is UTC Time
*
FROM CRActivity where subject like '%test%CR%'
```

try using the formula of

```
=[Activity.StartDate]
=[Activity.EndDate]
```

in your GI data field. This will grab the raw values. I tried pulling together a formula using DateAdd and DateDiff in the data field, but the above is the closest I got.

This blog post has information on DateTime conversions from UTC but when I try using `=[Activity.EndDate] + NowUTC() - Now()` gets me a "Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator." error.

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/02/generic-inquiry-tips-tricks.html